# Checking for null values if element does not exist

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, resx, xelement

I am getting values for a number of elements in a `.resx` file. On some of the the `data` elements the `<comment>` child element does not exist so when I run the following I will get a `NullReferenceException`.

```
foreach (var node in XDocument.Load(filePath).DescendantNodes())
{
    var element = node as XElement;

    if (element?.Name == "data")
    {
        values.Add(new ResxString
        {
            LineKey = element.Attribute("name").Value,
            LineValue = element.Value.Trim(),
            LineComment = element.Element("comment").Value  //fails here
        });
    }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
LineComment = element.Element("comment").Value != null ? 
              element.Element("comment").Value : ""
```

And:

```
LineComment = element.Element("comment").Value == null ?
              "" : element.Element("comment").Value
```

However I am still getting an error? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Notice -- seems like the problem is you are doing .Value on "null" aka null.Value

Comment: What about using the null propagation operator (`?.`), like you did with in your `if` condition... `element.Element("comment")?.Value`. Or just `LineComment = element.Element("comment") == null ? "" : element.Element("comment").Value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (`?.`) Operator:

```
LineComment = element.Element("comment")?.Value
```

It used to test for null **before** performing a member access.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use Linq, don't just partially use it:
(Just expanding on [S. Akbari's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46103987/209259))

```
values = XDocument.Load(filePath)
  .DescendantNodes()
  .Select(dn => dn as XElement)
  .Where(xe => xe?.Name == "data")
  .Select(xe => new new ResxString
  {
         LineKey = element.Attribute("name").Value,
         LineValue = element.Value.Trim(),
         LineComment = element.Element("comment")?.Value 
  })
  .ToList();  // or to array or whatever
```

Comment: wouldn't `element` be `xe` in your example? Also, you might want to call out that you're using the null conditional operator, and that is where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Casting an element or attribute to a nullable type is enough. You'll either get the value or null.

```
var LineComment = (string)element.Element("comment");
```

or

```
var LineKey = (string)element.Attribute("name");
```